# Metal seems to interpret bgra8Unorm as an rgba color

Tags: swift, metal

In an Apple Metal app I am trying to edit texture contents. Texture uses bgra8Unorm pixel format and is created like this:

```
fileprivate var texture: MTLTexture!
private var buffer: MTLBuffer!
    
private var width: Int!
private var height: Int!

...

buffer = device.makeBuffer(length: width * height * 4, options: .storageModeManaged)
        
let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .bgra8Unorm, width: width, height: height, mipmapped: false)
texture = buffer.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor, offset: 0, bytesPerRow: width * 4)
```

I am setting pixel color as following:

```
func setPixel(x: Int, y: Int, color: NSColor) {
    let ptr = buffer.contents().bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: buffer.length / 4)

    var b: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        
    let index = y * width + x
    ptr[index] = (UInt32(b * 255) << 24) | (UInt32(g * 255) << 16) | (UInt32(r * 255) << 8) | UInt32(a * 255)
    buffer.didModifyRange(index..<(index + 1))
}
```

Main pixel format is also set to `bgra8Unorm` inheriting `MTKView`:

```
init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero, device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice())
        colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Fragment shader doesn't do anything interesting at all:

```
fragment float4 basic_fragment(
                              VertexOut inVert [[ stage_in ]],
                              texture2d<float> tex2D [[ texture(0) ]],
                              sampler sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]]
                              ) {
    return tex2D.sample(sampler2D, inVert.tex);
}
```

However, when I am calling all this to set the color of the pixel to be `NSColor.orange` is appears to be blue.

[image: Blue color instead of the orange]

Running the debugger and capturing the GPU frame, I can see that the value in the buffer is `8388607` which looks like maxed `Alpha`, `Red`, and almost maxed `Green`. But somehow Metal seems to interpret this color as being in `rgba` format, despite me setting everything to `bgra`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

`bgra` means that 4 components `b`, `g`, `r` and `a` appears in this order in memory.
So, in little endian `UInt32`, `b` should be the LS byte and `a` the MS byte.

Please try this:

```
    ptr[index] = (UInt32(a * 255) << 24) | (UInt32(r * 255) << 16) | (UInt32(g * 255) << 8) | UInt32(b * 255)
```

Comment: Right. This seems to work. I found a sentence in the documentation saying that colours are stored in little-endian. However, in my code I am working in terms of UInt32, and somehow I assumed almost all modern architectures are little-endian too. So, I expected memory write to do everything right. Does it ultimately mean that Apple M1 chip uses big-endian, or am I missing something?

Comment: @saferif, M1 chip is little-endian as well as Intel, and in little-endian, the least significant byte comes first.

Comment: I know you have answered my original question, and this all might be out of the scope, but I would be grateful if you could help me understand this.
If both M1 chip and GPU use little-endian byte order, how does the order of bytes become messed up? Should the memory write do everything correctly. In little-endian, the least significant byte comes first. In my original code the least significant is `a`, and shouldn't it get written first as expected?

Comment: @saferif, "the least significant is `a`" -- right, "shouldn't it get written first as expected?" -- it should. But you are specifying `bgra`, so Metal expects the first byte as `b`.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. I thought `bgra` means that `b` is MSB and `a` is LSB, which, when written in little-endian, automatically turns into a correct thing. Thank you very much for clarification and your help.